# Azure resource group URL

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

Is there any URL to directly go to Azure resource group.

I am having a dashboard which has many RGs displayed there.
so I want to go to that RG directly if I click on it.
can we use something like below url which takes to azure health

*https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Health/AzureHealthBrowseBlade/resourceHealth*

I have tried below. But is not working.

*https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Resource_group/*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer which will take you to RG
'https://portal.azure.com/#@TENANTNAME/resource/subscriptions/(subscriptionID)/resourceGroups/(RGName)/overview'

Answer (score 0):

In Resource Group -> Properties you've got "Resource ID", which is the path to you RG.

So you need to concat

```
https://portal.azure.com/#blade>/resource/<Resource ID>
```

For me it looks like

```
https://portal.azure.com/#blade/resource/subscriptions/<subscription ID>/resourceGroups/<Group name>/overview
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go to a specifc resource group, it should be like below, replace the `tenantname`, `<subscription-id>`, `<resource-groupname>` of yours.

```
https://portal.azure.com/#@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com/resource/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-groupname>/overview
```

If you want to browse all the resource groups, it should be

```
https://portal.azure.com/#blade/HubsExtension/BrowseResourceGroups
```

Actually, you just need to navigate to it in the azure portal, then copy the URL in the browser, that is what you want.

**Update:**

To make the answer more clear, also add two other ways to go to a specifc resource group.

```
https://portal.azure.com/#@<customdomain of your AAD tenant>/resource/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-groupname>/overview

https://portal.azure.com/#@<tenant-id>/resource/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-groupname>/overview
```

Comment: this is correct
https://portal.azure.com/#@TENANTNAME.com/resource/subscriptions/(SubscriptionID)/resourceGroups/(RGName)/overview

Comment: @Ac9293 This is not correct, you need to use `tenantname.onmicrosoft.com` instead of `tenantname.com` as my answer. You can also use the `tenant-id` instead of `tenantname.onmicrosoft.com` in my answer, it is also correct.

Comment: i just tested what i have commented..it is working for me
yours might be correct in different case.

Comment: @Ac9293 I suppose the `TENANTNAME.com` you mentioned should be the custom domain of your azure ad tenant, if so, it will also work, if you use the primary domain name here, it will not work.

Comment: @Ac9293 Please do not thank me, I think you have not tested my answer at all, and if you really want to thank me, you will not give up to accept the most complete answer, and accept your own . why you still uses `TENANTNAME` in your answer? It should be the domain name or the custom domain name, it is different from the tenant name, you are misleading the community members.